# How do I SELECT the oldest record in a table PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with columns `account_id` and `creation_date`. The `creation_date` gets the current timestamp when the account is created (row is inserted) - how can I get the oldest account to return? In other words, the row which has the earliest timestamp in the table?

I've tried `SELECT account_id, MIN(creation_date) FROM table` but can't seem to get `MIN()` to work how I'd like it to.

Comment: Order the results with the `ORDER BY` clause and then pick the first record with `LIMIT` clause: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY creation_date LIMIT 1`

Comment: Pretty basic sql here, what did you try?

Comment: @JNevill: your comment deserves to be published as an answer (to make it more easily discoverable: imagine 20 tabs, you have just a glance at the page, to see whether there is amn adequate solution (and "order by + limit" should at least work-- I don't know how idiomatic it is: google suggests there seems to be many variants to solve this problem)

Comment: @sgeddes: some people do not write sql every day. If it were that basic there would be a single idiomatic solution for all the various sql dialects.

Comment: Blast from the past @jfs I will stick this in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was the way to do it:

`SELECT account_id, creation_date FROM table WHERE creation_date = (SELECT MIN(creation_date) FROM table)`

Comment: This is one way to do it, but it requires two passes at the table. The example I shared in the comment requires only a single pass. While I didn't downvote because it's a legit question and well written, I suspect it was downvoted due to the fact that is some super rudimentary sql that is covered [in many places](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS785US785&ei=cUotW6_tE4bKjwSOv5_YDg&q=how+to+select+the+first+record+by+date+postgres&oq=how+to+select+the+first+record+by+date+postgres) (lack of research is in the hover text for the downvote button).

Comment: @JNevill . . . This would probably be highly efficient if the table has an index on `creation_date`.

Answer (score 4):

You can order the results with the `ORDER BY` clause and then pick the first record with `LIMIT` clause:

```
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY creation_date LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't you just do:

```
select t.account_id
from t
order by creation_date
fetch first 1 row only;
```